# Generate PDF on React js doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, redux-saga

I got this problem when I try to export PDF report which is design Jaspersoft® Studio the method do all, but it doesn't download the PDF

I use reactjs v16.0 and spring boot 2.0
spring boot use for generate pdf and reactjs use for call rest api rest api

My code details are below

**React js code :**

```
   export function* downloadMarkSheetByRollRange() {    
   const requestURL = "http://192.168.31.215:8083/marksheet/single/download?startRoll=1&endRoll=20&classConfigId=100148&examConfigId=53&marksheetYear=2017"
   const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  console.log(requestURL);
  const result = yield call(request, requestURL, options);
}

export default function* defaultSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(SUBMIT_DOWNLOAD, downloadMarkSheetByRollRange);

} 

Here is my index.js page

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { compose } from 'redux';

import injectSaga from 'utils/injectSaga';
import injectReducer from 'utils/injectReducer';
import makeSelectGeneralExamMarkSheet from './selectors';
import reducer from './reducer';
import saga from './saga';
import messages from './messages';
import { Button } from 'primereact/components/button/Button';

export class GeneralExamMarkSheet extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render() {   
 return (
      <div>
        <Panel header="General Exam MarkSheet" >
          <Button label="Download" icon="ui-icon-search" onClick = 
                {this.props.downloadMarkSheet} >
           </Button>
        </Panel>
     </div>
  );
 }
}

GeneralExamMarkSheet.propTypes = {};
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
          dispatch,
  };
}
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const withReducer = injectReducer(
 { 
  key:'generalExamMarkSheet',reducer
 });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'generalExamMarkSheet', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(GeneralExamMarkSheet);
```

But when i hit http://192.168.31.215:8083/marksheet/single/download?startRoll=1&endRoll=20&classConfigId=100148&examConfigId=53&marksheetYear=2017 url in browser then generate pdf

Here is my browser response when try to react js

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: `Accept` is set to `application/json`. Also, you won't be able to trigger user download like this. You either need to create an `<a>` link with `download` (or other param), or you need to simulate a form request.

Comment: Sir kindly give me a simulate a form request sample or <a> link with download.

Comment: Uh, `<a download href="http://192.168.31.215:8083/marksheet/single/download?startRoll=1&endRoll=20&classConfigId=100148&examConfigId=53&marksheetYear=2017">{this.props.downloadMarkSheet}</a>`.

Comment: Problem is solved, Thank you sir